# How to find 2% less price from two sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hope you are all having a great day. here am with a trouble that needs your help to move on. I have a sheet below a small sample of my work. I will get products every months from different suppliers, most of all products are common in two months but with a small price variation.I don't need to verify the products which i verified last month. I got a solution for displaying new products. but need to find out the products which are cheaper than previous month. so here i want to display the new products + products which are at least 2% cheaper than previous week. Hope you understand what my problem is in my sheet there is an example of how output must be. that will give you little more idea.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m8bwVUgKysQGS0kFt3zRwnquuH_Tou0ouajoM80Lg68/edit?pli=1#gid=502304505

Thanks in advance

Comment: I helped you with your first post on this issue. Very little has changed besides the sheet names. So it seems that you just don't know how to adjust formulas yourself. However, I see that in the above sheet, you have references to A2:I, but there is only data showing in A2:E in this sheet. Does your real sheet have data to copy in A2:I? Or do you only need A2:E in your real sheet, as shown in this sheet? If you can tell me this much, I will adjust the formulas for you one time so that they work again. But then you will need to figure out how to apply them to your real sheet.

Comment: Also, your sheet called "estimated result of Products 2% less price" shows items that are 2% less AND new products from the "Second Month" sheet. Do you really want the items that are 2% less AND all new items from "Second Month"? Or do you want ONLY the items that are 2% less? Please be sure and answer carefully so that I can make changes one time only.

Comment: @Erick.. Thanks i will try to convey as much as i can. in my real sheet i have references from A2:E. and i want the items which are 2% less and all new items from second month.

Comment: I have updated the formulas in "New Products" and "Products 2% less price." As you can see, they are working. Since this was a fix to a previous issue, and since there are no other solutions offered by contributors here, I recommend that you delete this entire post from Stack, since it adds no new information for future users.

Comment: @Erick its fine now i got what is the issue. the formula doesn't takes number format. see when i  changed the code as numbers 'New Products' not showing output. if that one can be fixed everything is perfect.

Comment: Just set the formatting for your "Code" columns to "Plain Text" (Format > Number > Plain text).